# mysql Count multiple occurrences of multiplexed entries

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table as shown below,

```
  id          reasonCode
------      ------------------
  1           0, 1
  2           0
  3           1, 2, 3
  4           2
  5           1, 0
```

And I want output as

```
  reasonCode           occurrences

    0                      3
    1                      3
    2                      2
    3                      1
```

I tried "group by" but it gives something like this.

```
  reasonCode           occurrences

    0, 1                   1
    0                      1
    1, 2, 3                1
    2                      1
    1, 0                   1
```

if someone have any idea of how to do it, will be appreciated.

Comment: RDBMS are not appropriate to hold multi-valued data in one cell. Please normalize you table structure (before it is too late). Only one `reasonCode` should be stored in one row (instead of a comma separated value). What you are trying to do maybe possible but may incur overhead and performance issues.

Comment: @AzizShaikh, Actually reasonCode is stored as varChar(45) datatype and the reason behind storing multiple values is that there may be more than one reason to stop machine and that should come in single entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table of reason codes (I presume you do, so you know what the meaning is of reason code 1 for example) then you could just do something like this:-

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.id)
FROM reason_codes a
LEFT OUTER JOIN id_reason_code b
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, b.reasonCode)
GROUP BY a.id
```

However one problem with this is that you have spaces after the commas. A comma separated field is a problem at the best of times (better split off into multiple rows of another table - easy enough to concatenate them together afterwards if needs be), but the spaces after the commas will give issues (note that removing these spaces would also make the solution by @Vignesh Kumar a bit simpler).

To get round this you could do:-

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.id)
FROM reason_codes a
LEFT OUTER JOIN id_reason_code b
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, REPLACE(b.reasonCode, ' ', ''))
GROUP BY a.id
```

EDIT - Explanation

It is just a LEFT OUTER JOIN. This will take every row from the first table (ie, reason codes), and match that against any row that matches on the 2nd table (ie, ie_reason_code - not sure what your table is called that you show above); if there are no matching rows on the 2nd table then the row from the first table is still brought back but with NULL in the columns from the 2nd table. In this case the join is done based on FIND_IN_SET. This looks for the first parameter in a list of comma separated values and returns the position if found (hence if found it evaluates to true).

The COUNT / GROUP BY then counts the number of values of b.id for each a.id and presents that count.

The 2nd query is doing the same, but it is removing any spaces from the comma separated list before checking for values (required when you have a space as well as a comma separating the values).

If you had the following tables:-

```
reason_codes table
id  reason
0   Reason A
1   Reason B
2   Reason C
3   Reason D
4   Reason E

id_reason_code table
id          reasonCode
1           0,1
2           0
3           1,2,3
4           2
5           1,0
```

then the following sql (removing the COUNT / GROUP BY):-

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM reason_codes a
LEFT OUTER JOIN id_reason_code b
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, b.reasonCode)
```

would give something like the following:-

```
a.id    b.id
0       1
0       2
0       5
1       1
1       3
1       5
2       3
2       4
3       3
4       NULL
```

Running:-

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.id)
FROM reason_codes a
LEFT OUTER JOIN id_reason_code b
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, b.reasonCode)
GROUP BY a.id
```

the COUNT / GROUP BY is giving one row for each value of a.id, and then a count of the values (non null) of b.id for that value of a.id:-

```
a.id    count(b.id)
0       3
1       3
2       2
3       1
4       0
```

You could also bring back the actual reason instead of the code if you wanted:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.reason, COUNT(b.id)
FROM reason_codes a
LEFT OUTER JOIN id_reason_code b
ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, b.reasonCode)
GROUP BY a.id, a.reason
```

giving:-

```
a.id    a.reason    count(b.id)
0       Reason A    3
1       Reason B    3
2       Reason C    2
3       Reason D    1
4       Reason E    0
```

Comment: Thanks, will you please explain the query?

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help. Its very useful query to me especially last one but my reason codes have comma in between, how to remove them in your last query ? thanks for your help, it will simplify my coding in software.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand you. That should cope with commas (but nothing else) between the reason code ids so I think I have misunderstood the issue you have with it. Could you put up a couple of sample tables showing the issue please?

Comment: I think you understood right, when i tried this query on my table there are two entries in my reasonCode column as "1,3" and "2, 1, 3". So, in output entry "3" comes twice, one with space and one without space. (Actually i can force data logger engineer to not fill with spaces, but that's not good idea). Can we use TRIM() like function here ?

Comment: I think if you just use `REPLACE(b.reasonCode, ' ', '')` to remove the spaces. However without that I wouldn't expect it to match the one with a space at the moment. Unless you have 2 entries on your table of reason codes. If you could set up an SQL fiddle for it I will have a better idea.

Comment: All write i will use 'REPLACE'. Thanks for your help with explanation, very few people do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT Reason,COUNT(Reason) FROM
(
SELECT
  id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(reasoncode, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) Reason
FROM
  table1
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(reasoncode, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(reasoncode)-n.digit
ORDER BY
  id,
  n.digit
) T

Group By Reason;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32767f/3)**

Output Would be:

```
REASON  OCCURANCES
0           3
1           3
2           2
3           1
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. Actually, the num of reason codes are going to change. User can add/remove reason codes whenever he wants.

Comment: Can you state that with sample data

Comment: I mean there is a config table on screen(which is also in mysql db) in which user is able to enter reasons and there reasonCodes. for eg. for reason code "0" reason is "maintenance", for reason code "1" reason is "material shortage" and may be on other day he will interchange that reasonCodes.

Comment: So, there may be five or six or more reason codes and am interested in how many times they occurred. Is this possible with mysql?

Comment: Hey, I tried your query and its working great. It working for scalable reason codes as well, thanks. Can you please explain query because i didn't understand it. thanks again.

Comment: @ashok In the subquery we are splitting comma seperated values into separate row. see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32767f/5. After that simple we gonna count each reason

Comment: thanks, it seems hard to digest to me, anyway I am gonna use it now and will think later. I didn't thought that I will get answer within one hour, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> *...the num of reason codes are going to change. User can add/remove reason codes whenever he wants...*

If what numbers would be there as part of reason codes is not known, then you better generate the query dynamic. You can do this by a stored procedure.

**Steps to follow**:

1. Fetch each reason code string in to a variable.
2. Split it to find each of the reason codes.
3. Generate a `select` with found code and its count as 1.
4. `Union all` all such statements if generated some.
5. Loop until no more codes are present in each string.
6. Repeat until all rows are processed
7. Now, run an aggregate function on the generated result sets group by
   reason code.
8. You have the results in hand.

**Part of sample code snippet**:

```
-- ...

set @sql_query := 'select reason_code, sum(rc_count) as rc_count from (' ;
set @sql_query := 
       concat( @sql_query, 
               '\n  ( select null as reason_code, 0 as rc_count )' );

-- ...

splitting_reason_codes: loop
  set comma_position = locate( ',', reason_code_string );
  if comma_position then
    set rc := substring( reason_code_string, 1, comma_position-1 );
    set reason_code_string := 
            substring( reason_code_string, comma_position+1 );
  else
    set rc := reason_code_string;
  end if;

  if length( rc ) > 0 then
    set @sql_query := 
            concat( @sql_query, 
                    '\n   union all ( select ', rc, ', 1 )' );
  end if;

  if ! comma_position then
    leave splitting_reason_codes;
  end if;
end loop splitting_reason_codes;

-- ...

set @sql_query := concat( @sql_query, '\n) unique_reason_codes' );
set @sql_query := concat( @sql_query, '\nwhere reason_code is not null' );
set @sql_query := concat( @sql_query, '\ngroup by reason_code' );
set @sql_query := concat( @sql_query, '\norder by reason_code' );

prepare stmt from @sql_query;
execute stmt;
```

**Demo** @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adf8/1)