# calculating the word occurrence in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the reviews from different sites and storing into table. For each review I am getting `adjective` and `noun` list in separate column.

So for each review there are main 3 values here.

`review, adjective_list, rate`

Now I want to count number of times adjectives repeats. After that recommending only those review which has adjectives which repeats maximum time and having review 4-5.

Which is correct way to do this?

My thought about this:

Creating trigger which perform action when ever there is insert review operation.
This trigger will read column having adjectives, calculate the occurrence(**don't know how?**) and storing top adjectives with their occurrence.

While recommendation selecting adjective with maximum occurrence, and looking into 4-5 rated review.

I am not sure what is correct way. Any help is appreciable

Main table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Is your list of adjectives a string with comma delimited words or does each adjective belong in a separate record?

Comment: Can you post just a few rows of sample data? I have an idea :)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: thanks dude, There is one column for adjectives. Which contains list of all adjetive with comma separated for each review.

Comment: Occurences are counted as the length of string where the word is replaced with empty over the number the letters in that word.Use Replace.

Comment: `(length(column)-length(replace(column,'word','')))/4`

Comment: @Programming_crazy: A workaround solution but similar is [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22860123/767881)

Comment: @mihai - Be careful here.  How many times does the word `'poo'` appear in this list?  `'spoon,pooh,pootle'`  I say 0 times, your function says 3 times.  You need to do something like `',poo,'` in `',spoon,pooh,pootle,'`.

Comment: @MatBailie And probably Concating commas at the beginning and end also.Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: do you have any solution for this?

Comment: @Programming_crazy I had the same idea as `Mihai`, but apparently `MatBailie` was right words that might contain the word you're trying to count.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but if I understand you requirement correctly you should be able to base a query on something like this to do the job:-

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(adj_noun, ',', aCnt + 1), ',', -1), COUNT(*)
FROM Main_Table
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Units.i + Tends.i * 10 + Hundreds.i * 100 AS aCnt
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Hundreds
) Integers_Query
ON aCnt <= (LENGTH(adj_noun) - LENGTH(REPLACE(adj_noun, ',', '')))
GROUP BY id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(adj_noun, ',', aCnt + 1), ',', -1)
```

This uses a subquery to get a range of numbers (0 to 999), and does a join of this against your table where the number is less than or equal to the number of time a comma appears in the adj_noun column (ie, subtract the length of adj_noun with all the commas removed from the full length of adj_noun). Then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the string up to the aCnt comma, and again use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the string from that comma back to the previous comma (excludes the commas from the result).

The COUNT / GROUP BY should get you the number of times each word appears in the resulting list for each item.

Probably fairly inefficient. Only copes with 1000 comma separated words (easily extended, but will be slower).

Comment: I really dont understand the query fully, but this sort of query need to be executed in backend or when user make query for data items?

Comment: This query is just to get a list of rows, one for each word for each id, and the count of the number of times that word is used for that id. You could possibly use this in a trigger, specifying the id to get the details to populate another table. I am a bit unsure as to exactly what you need the output for hence this was just an example of how to extract the values.